# Raising the Sleep HD limit

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

In Pathfinder the spells [Sleep](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sleep/) and [Deep Slumber](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/deep-slumber/) both have caps on how many Hit Dice worth of creatures they can affect, and this limit doesn't increase with level.

For some reason I recall seeing either an archetype, feat, spell or other ability that raises this HD cap or otherwise allows sleep spells to affect more creatures. Of course, now I can't find it by searching (I must have just dreamed the whole thing...). I know the [Heavens Oracle](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo---oracle-mysteries/heavens) does something similar to this but for Illusion (pattern) spells, with its Awesome Display power.

Are there any archetypes, feats, spells, or abilities that raise the HD cap of these spells and what source are they from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing quite like the *awesome display* oracle revelation for *sleep* and/or *deep slumber* that I am aware of. There are, however, things that work like *sleep* or *deep slumber* but with higher or no HD caps.

- [Mythic *sleep*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells#TOC-Sleep) has an 8-HD limit, and [mythic *deep slumber*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic/augmented-spells#TOC-Deep-Slumber) has a 20-HD limit.
- The [sandman bard archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo-bard-archetypes/sandman/) gets a spell-like ability that is “as *deep slumber*, but with no HD limit,” but that is only when using that particular ability, rather than a change made to the *sleep* or *deep slumber* spells that the sandman might cast.
- Similarly, the [*slumber* witch hex](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes-3rd-party-publishers/hexes/common-hexes/hex-slumber-su/) is “as per the spell *sleep*” and “can affect a creature of any HD.” Again, that is only while using *slumber* and does not apply to any *sleep* or *deep slumber* spells.

Answer (score 2):

Having a negative level subtracts a hit die for all effects that count hit dice.

So if you hit a 14 HD creature with Enervation and roll a 4, it counts as a 10 HD creature for Deep Slumber.